# Need clarification on the meaning of Resharper NotNullAttribute

Tags: annotations, resharper, notnull

Consider the following code:

```
    public static void Foo()
    {
        Bar(null);
    }

    public static void Bar([NotNull] string s)
    {
        if (s == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("s");
    }
```

The `[NotNull]` attribute is used on `Bar` to tell callers that `s` shouldn't be null. This works fine, and I get a warning when I pass null to `Bar` (*Possible 'null' assignment to entity marked with 'NotNull' attribute*).

But it doesn't actually prevent me from passing null, so `Bar` must still check if `s` is null. **So why am I also getting a warning on `if (s == null)` (*Expression is always false*)** ?

As far as I can tell, this attribute has an ambiguous meaning; depending on context, it can mean two different things:

- for the caller: *don't pass a null argument*
- for the callee: *this argument is not null*

Am I using this attribute correctly, or am I missing something?

BTW, I'm using Resharper 7 EAP, so it might be a bug; however I want to make sure my usage is correct before I report it...

---

EDIT: just tried the same thing with R# 5.1 at work; it shows the warning on the call site, but not in the method. I'll report it on Jetbrain's Youtrack.

---

EDIT2: bug reported [here](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-304111)

Comment: What happens if you add a second caller which passes something other than `null`? Could be that v7 does more insightful value source analysis and sees that in this case the only caller of `Bar` passes `null`...

Comment: btw as far as I know, the semantics of this attribute are *only* the first of your bullet points; it is a declaration by the method to the outside world.

Comment: @AakashM, good point, but if it did this analysis, it should say "expression is always true", not always false... Anyway, I tried to add a call with a non-null value for s, and it still gives the same warning.

Comment: Oh whoops, completely missed that it was the wrong way round!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you're using it right and ReSharper is wrong to tell you the comparison is always `false`. The `[NotNull]` attribute is no more than documentation and your code is right to double-check the input values. It wouldn't be the first time ReSharper made a wrong or stupid suggestion. The cool thing about JetBrains is that they have [a public bug tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RSRP) where you can report this and get feedback straight from the devs.

That said, (and forgive me if you're aware of it), [C# 4.0's Code Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264808.aspx) makes this easy, predictable, and reliable:

```
Contract.RequiresAlways(s != null);
```

Comment: Apparently it has been fixed in the final version of R# 7